# How does recovery mode affect the subsequent boot?

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel

I have a situation with nvidia where the system refuses to put up the login screen unless I boot into recovery mode, drop into root, do nothing other than continue with a normal boot.

When I don't do the initial boot into recovery mode, I get a tty login prompt or just a blank screen. ctrl-alt-f7 show a repeating failure to start the nvidia persistence daemon.

If I first boot to recover mode then continue with the normal boot. I don't see the nvidia failure.

I am wondering what it is about the recovery mode that makes the next normal boot come up differently.

This is the 16.04 system on a Lenovo P50.

Richard

Comment: Have you tried adding the `nomodeset` kernel parameter?

Comment: When you boot into recovery mode and then select `resume` from the recovery menu, it will boot the system without loading the graphics driver. That's why you don't run into the nvidia problem this way. You could uninstall all nvidia packages (`sudo apt purge nvidia-*`) to be able to boot normally, and then figure out how to really fix it.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I will try nomodeset. I didn't realise it would be rembered even if we go back to BIOS for a reboot.  It does seem that nvidia support is a bit suspect for the combination of h/w I have.  I have been through quite a journey with different drivers for nvidia. Seems that nvidia-381 is the most stable, but still not devoid of problems,