# Boot: Normal vs Recovery

Tags: boot, 18.04, login-screen

After a recent update to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, my system hangs during boot (see my first question at [18.04.2 Hangs during boot after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151034/18-04-2-hangs-during-boot-after-update)).

This time I am asking for help to learn about what would be different between just letting the system boot normally and booting into the recovery system and then immediately choosing to resume booting (without doing **ANYTHING** else while in the recovery console.)  I am curious because it appears to me that the actual logon program is never starting (or silently failing during start) when I boot normally, but it works fine when I boot through the recovery/resume method.

I would like to correct the normal boot so that it actually works without requiring me to jump through the recover/resume hoop.  Are there any experts in these two different booting mechanisms that are willing to help me?

EDIT:  I just checked and found out that I can use PuTTY (ssh) to connect and login to the system while it is hung prior to displaying the login screen.  So it definitely appears that the login screen is failing to start as it should.  I have tried comparing the syslog from a failed (normal) boot and a successful (recover/resume) boot, but they are VERY different and I understand very, very little of what is logged during boot.

For personal reference, I develop some software on/for linux (about 20kloc) but work primarily on Windows (over 1000kloc).  I can check/try things when asked, but simply don't know enough about the bowels of linux to figure this one out on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question, I started reading the related articles that askubuntu offered and found this one: [How does recovery mode affect the subsequent boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924012/how-does-recovery-mode-affect-the-subsequent-boot?rq=1)

So, I gave the nomodeset boot parameter a try and it worked.  Apparently something included with a recent update made this parameter necessary.  FWIW, I'm running under VMware Player 15, with whatever video emulation it provides.  Regardless, adding nomodeset fixed my boot problem.